# Set noindex for Google structured data

Tags: robots.txt, structured-data, noindex

I'm using multiple blocks of structured data on my website:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Event",
    "name": "Something",
    "url": "http://www.example.com/?id=123"
    }
</script>
```

This will show another bar under the search results of my website to directly visit the page to see more details about the event.

But if providing links like `http://www.example.com/?id=123` Google will also show this link as `normal` link in search results.

But if setting `noindex` for this webpage Google will also refuse to list the events, won't it?

Does anybody know a solution?

Here's an image what I mean:

[image]

Comment: 1) Are you sure that this event list comes from the structured data? As far as I know, Google parses this directly from the page content (typically from lists or tables). 2) What do you want to achieve? You want to `noindex` the event page, but keep the event linked in the search result for a parent page?

Comment: 1) Yes, I am. Google can only parse it if they're using special code. Or if you use structured data. 2) You're right, sounds strange, hard to explain. I think it's not possible. I'll try something other.

Answer (score 0):

Put a canonical link with value http://www.example.com/ on the http://www.example.com/?id=123 page. All pages with query parameters will be merged into http://www.example.com/ regarding rankings.